# mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I go to run a python code directly through the terminal it gives me this error, I've already tried to reinstall numpy and it didn't work!

And I tried to install mlk service returns the same error. Can someone help me ?

```
UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu 
OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\teste.user\Desktop\Project-python\teste.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\teste.user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\teste.user\Anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: How did you install numpy?

Comment: You could try to update numpy or force reinstall. conda install numpy --force-reinstall

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can be solved by resetting package configuration by force reinstall of numpy.

```
conda install numpy --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it by running the following commands to uninstall and reinstall the packages

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip uninstall pillow
pip uninstall numpy
pip install matplotlib
pip install pillow
pip install numpy
```